# How do I add a column to an existing excel file using python?

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

here is my code:

```
import openpyxl, pprint
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('/Users/sarahporgess/Desktop/SSA1.xlsx')
sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')


data = {}
for row in range(1,sheet.max_row+1):


        date = sheet['A' +str(row)].value
        gamma = sheet['B' +str(row)].value
        theta = sheet['C' +str(row)].value
        ratio = float(gamma)/float(theta)
        resultFile = open('SSA2.csv' , 'w')
        resultFile.write( pprint.pformat(date))
        resultFile.write( pprint.pformat(gamma))
        resultFile.write( pprint.pformat(theta))

        resultFile.write( pprint.pformat(ratio))
        print(ratio)
        sheet['D1']=ratio
resultFile.close()
print('Done.')
```

my existing excel file currently has three columns: "date, gamma, theta". I want to add a fourth column called "ratio" that is the ratio of gamma/theta. How do I add another column to an existing excel document using python? 
This code creates an excel document with the 4 elements printed into one cell

Comment: is there a reason for SSA2.csv to be a csv and not xlsx?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is easier to use the Pandas package

```
import pandas as pd
file_name = #Path to your file
df = pd.read_excel(file_name) #Read Excel file as a DataFrame

df['Ratio'] = df['Gamma']/df['Theta']
#Display top 5 rows to check if everything looks good
df.head(5)

#To save it back as Excel
df.to_excel("path to save") #Write DateFrame back as Excel file
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is my first time seeing the code "df.to_excel("path to save")", can you explain this line please?

Comment: Here is what the code does: It reads the Excel file as a DataFrame, which is a data structure that represents tabular data. After reading the Excel File as a DataFrame, there is a lot of things that you can do, including transformations, joins, merges, mathematical operations etc. `df.to_excel()` simply writes the DataFrame back to disk as an Excel File

Comment: While Pandas is a great library it's not the best tool for editing Excel files.

Answer (score 2):

From your updated question I have rewrote my answer.

You don't need to use another library to accomplish what you are trying to do.
Here is another option for accomplishing what you want.

```
import openpyxl
import pprint

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('/Users/sarahporgess/Desktop/SSA1.xlsx')
sheet = wb.active
# you may also use the wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1') method here.


data = {}
for row in range(1,sheet.max_row+1):
        date = sheet.cell(row = row, column = 1) # use .cell() to get values of cells
        gamma = sheet.cell(row = row, column = 2)
        theta = sheet.cell(row = row, column = 3)
        print(date, gamma, theta)
        ratio = float(gamma)/float(theta)
        new_wb = openpyxl.Workbook() # creates new workbook to be saved as results
        # you can also open a wookbook here instead but I wrote it to create a results workbook as I didnt already have one.
        new_sheet = new_wb.active
        new_sheet['A1'] = pprint.pformat(date)
        new_sheet['B1'] = pprint.pformat(gamma)
        new_sheet['C1'] = pprint.pformat(theta)
        new_sheet['D1'] = pprint.pformat(ratio)
        print(ratio)
        # save new workbook as SSA2
        new_wb.save('/Users/sarahporgess/Desktop/SSA2.xlsx')

print('Done.')
```

Comment: typo! I meant column, Thanks though!

Comment: @SarahPorgess: I have updated my answer to use your current imports.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear from your code whether you want to print the result or edit the existing file. If you're editing an Excel file then you might want to create a formula and let Excel do the calculation for you.

```
import openpyxl
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('/Users/sarahporgess/Desktop/SSA1.xlsx')
sheet = wb['Sheet1']

for row in sheet:
     date, gamma, theta = row
     ratio = theta.offset(column=1)
     ratio.value = "=B{0}/C{0}".format(theta.row) # if you want the formula
     # ratio.value = gamma/theta # if you just want the calculation

wb.save(…)
```

Comment: he is adding the results to another file.

Comment: In which case the question is misleading.

Comment: Sometimes people are not able to articulate their questions well. That is why I review the code and from the question and the content of the code decide on what their question really is. This approach has proven more accurate than not.

Comment: Saving to another file is merely the filename you pass to the `save()` method. More important is to make as use of the openpyxl API for this kind of thing: no need to create a loop, no need to use `pprint`, use of the `offset` method.

Comment: I imaging the loop is there for multiple rows of date that need the same process done to them. I don't think they are only performing this function one one row of data. Also I agree pprint does not appear to be needed however because the OP is using pprint I answer with the use of pprint as well.

Comment: Compare the original code with my suggestion. openpyxl provides all the necessary methods for this so that it is never necessary to create counters (`max_row` might not be available), etc.

Comment: I did see you used `sheet` instead of `max_row`. I am not fully versed in openpyxl so my answer was to solve the OPs problem and leave the rest of their code intact as is.

Comment: Familiarity with domain specific libraries makes for better answers. EOT.