# how to insert a new column before an existing column using python?

Tags: python-3.x, openpyxl

I have tried calling shift method from the `Cell_Range` class using worksheet object, but I get an error:

> Cell_Range is not attribute of worksheet.

Need help to insert a column before an existing column in a sheet.

```
wrkbk=load_workbook("test.xlsx")
wrkbksheetnames=wrkbk.sheetnames
for sheetname in wrkbksheetnames:
    if sheetname=="Bell Pricing Grid Summary":
        ws=wrkbk[sheetname]
        ws["E":"H"]
wrkbk.save("test.xlsx")
```

Comment: are you using openpyxl? If so you should add the corresponding tag

Comment: It is much easier with panda have a look here may help you.. https://stackoverflow.com/a/44811753/7352806

Comment: Looks like you're just trying random stuff out. Why do you expect this to work? Worksheets do now have an `insert_cols()` method.