# Python, how to add a new column in excel

Tags: python, excel

I am having below file(file1.xlsx) as input. In total i am having 32 columns in this file and almost 2500 rows. Just for example i am mentioning 5 columns in screen print

[image]

I want to edit same file with python and want output as (file1.xlsx)
it should be noted i am adding one column named as short and data is a kind of substring upto first decimal of data present in name(A) column of same excel.
[image]

Request you to please help

Regards
Kawaljeet

Comment: Please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44811523/how-do-i-add-a-column-to-an-existing-excel-file-using-python). It can help.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you need...

```
import pandas as pd
file_name = "file1.xlsx"
df = pd.read_excel(file_name) #Read Excel file as a DataFrame
df['short'] = df['Name'].str.split(".")[0]
df.to_excel("file1.xlsx")
```

Comment: Thanks Soorajit, but I am getting error. To be more precised, i am having 32 columns in total in file and also i don't want to print that sequence number of data frame in excel file.
when I am executing this code i am getting error as "ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index"

Answer (score 0):

hello guys i solved the problem with below code:

```
import pandas as pd
import os
def add_column():
 file_name = "cmdb_inuse.xlsx"
 os.chmod(file_name, 0o777)
 df = pd.read_excel(file_name,) #Read Excel file as a DataFrame
 df['short'] = [x.split(".")[0] for x in df['Name']]
 df.to_excel("cmdb_inuse.xlsx", index=False)
```